# Выбор страницы из массива

Tags: php

Есть массив страниц, в котором ключ является название рубрики, а значение ключа является список страниц в этой рубрике.
**P.S.** исправил немного вопрос

```
$uri = 'page3/link3.1';
$pages = [
    'page1'=>[
        'link1'=>'ссылка1',
        'link1.2'=>'ссылка1.2',
        'link1.3'=>'ссылка1.3'
    ],
    'page2'=>[
        'link2.1'=>'ссылка2',
        'link2.2'=>'ссылка2.2',
        'link2.3'=>'ссылка2.3'
    ],
    'page3'=>[
        'link3.1'=>'ссылка3',
        'link3.2'=>'ссылка3.2',
        'link3.3'=>'ссылка3.3'
    ],
]
```

нужно сделать что-то на подобии связанных постов.
Подскажите, как правильно определить, допустим если находимся не на странице рубрики `page1`, а в подрубрике, т.е. значения массива `link1`, то нужно получить все подрубрики, кроме текущей  ?
К примеру зашли на страницу `page3/link3.1` значит нужно получить все страницы в текущей рубрике `page3` кроме link3.1.
Нужно получить значения ключей `link` чтобы вывести на русском названия связанных записей, кроме текущей.
Но если текущая страница `page3`, то все рубрики выводить не нужно

Comment: вам вроде бы достаточно будет поменять пару строк из предоставленного решения: [смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/785a11c5fb2329e12b3748a0c9fc3fb2cf6596eb)

Answer (score -1):

> К примеру зашли на страницу page3/link3.1 значит нужно получить все страницы в текущей рубрике page3 кроме link3.1

Вот вроде бы то, что вам нужно:

```
$pages = [
    'page1'=>[
        'link1'=>'ссылка1',
        'link1.2'=>'ссылка1.2',
        'link1.3'=>'ссылка1.3'
    ],
    'page2'=>[
        'link2.1'=>'ссылка2',
        'link2.2'=>'ссылка2.2',
        'link2.3'=>'ссылка2.3'
    ],
    'page3'=>[
        'link3.1'=>'ссылка3',
        'link3.2'=>'ссылка3.2',
        'link3.3'=>'ссылка3.3'
    ],
];

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
$array = explode('/', rtrim($uri, '/'));

if (count($array) > 1) {
    list($page, $link) = $array;
    $pages = $pages[$page] ?? [];

    foreach ($pages as $key => $url ) {
        $key == $link ?: print "$url<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: а можно для php < 7 ? кстати ваш код ничего не выводит на php7

Comment: параметры не нужны

Comment: @word тогда переформулируйте ваш первый пост, т.к. в нём написано обратное: _К примеру зашли на страницу page3/link3.1_

Comment: `page3/link3.1` тут нет get-параметров

Comment: @word ок, отбросим приставку get, если это так принципиально. Тогда что это тогда - субдомен `page3` и доменное имя `link3.1` ? __UPD__ : И зачем тогда вы приводите $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] если вы работаете НЕ с параметрами :)

Comment: можно было догадаться  вообще-то, что если есть массив ссылок, то других ссылок не может быть. $url для примера. можно взять ссылку из примера: `page3/link3.1`

Comment: @word как это других не может быть? O_o Вам адресная строка браузера не позволяет вводить другие ссылки? В общем, спорить с вами я не собираюсь, считайте как вам угодно =)